# Create an image gallery with react that has a max width and gets smaller once screen width becomes less than max width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an array of images (assume infinite amount) that is mapped out and rendered.

However right now its mapped vertically so like

img1

img2

.

.

I want it mapped horizontally and have a max width so that images will flow down once the width of the screen becomes smaller than the max width. How do you do so?

```
      <div>
        {this.state.imgs.map((imageUrl, i) => {
            return (
                <div key = {i}>{this.renderImage(imageUrl, "120", "170")}</div>
            );
        })
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: This can help you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ wtih Media Queries

Comment: try `display:flex` inside your css for the div class containing your images